# Why are my linked list modifications not working in this c code?

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list, malloc

This is my code, and I'm trying to add, print, delete, empty the list with a menu with user input but it doesn't hold or ouput any values. I debugged it by calling the functions outside of the loop and they work but the problem is that the calls don't output anything inside the loop.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
};

int Length(struct node* head);
void PrintList(struct node* head);
void Add(struct node** headRef, int new );
int Delete(struct node** headRef);
void ZeroList(struct node** headRef);

int main(void) {
    struct node * head = NULL;

    char enter;
    int x;
    Add( &head, 13 );
    printf("\na(add){x}\nd(del)\nl(ength)\np(rint)\nz(ero)\ne(xit)");
    do
    {
        fscanf(stdin, "%c", &enter);
        struct node *head = NULL;
        switch (enter)
        {
            case 'a': 
                printf("Enter a node: ");
                fscanf(stdin,"%d", &x);
                            Add(&head, x);
                break;
            case 'd':
                printf("Delete\n"); 
                Delete(&head);
                break;
            case 'l': 
                printf("Length");
                Length(head);
                break;
            case 'p':
                printf("printList");
                PrintList(head);
                break;
            case 'z': 
                printf("ZeroList");
                ZeroList(&head);
                break;
        }
    }while (enter != 'e');
    Add(&head, 23);
    PrintList(head);
    return 0;
}



//Debug
 /* Add( &head, 3 );
  Add( &head, 20 );
  Add( &head, 55 );
  Delete(&head);  
    Length(head);
  PrintList(head);
  ZeroList(&head);
   PrintList(head);*/

int Length(struct node* head) {
    struct node *current = head;
    int count = 0;
    while (current != NULL)
    {
        count++;
        current = current->next;
    }
    printf(" Size of head is %d\n", count);
    return(count);
}
void PrintList(struct node* head) {
    struct node *current = head;
    while (current != NULL)
    {
        printf("printing %d\n",  current->data);
        current = current->next;
    }
}
void Add(struct node** headRef, int new) {
    struct node *k = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    k->data = new;
    k->next = *headRef;
    *headRef = k;
    return;
}
int Delete(struct node** headRef) {
    struct node* current = *headRef;
    if (current == NULL)
    {
        printf("List is empty!\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Deleted value is: %d\n", current->data);
        *headRef = current->next;
        free(current);
    }
    return 0;
}

void ZeroList(struct node** headRef){
    struct node* current = *headRef;
    while (current != NULL)
    {
        current = current->next;
        free(current);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand the series of calls to `Add`, `Delete`, etc.  They are outside the body of any function.

Comment: Show a sample session and indicate which results are unexpected. "it doesn't hold or ouput any values" is not a helpful description of a problem. Though your trouble may have to do something with the fact that you never call `Add` inside the loop.

Comment: @CareyGregory These calls are supposed to moddify a linked list holding values 3,20,55. Add,uses the void Add() function to add numbers to the list, Delete() deletes numbers from the list.

Comment: But being outside the body of any function, they will never be executed.  In fact, I'm surprised this code compiles.

Comment: I can see lots of problems here. Why are you redeclaring `head` inside the `do` loop? Why are you fetching a value of `x` and doing nothing with it?

Comment: sorry, I put the add function, and removed it for debuggin

Comment: it was not working before but it still isn't with the add function inside the loop

Comment: I ran it and it works like a charm:) Paste in some sample output from a test-run.

Comment: output `a(add){x}
d(del)
l(ength)
p(rint)
z(ero)
e(xit)a
Enter a node: 55
p
printListe 
printing 23
`

Comment: It's suppose to print these 55,23,13

Comment: Did you remove `struct node *head = NULL;` from inside the loop? @squeamishossifrage suggested this. I did it kindof on autopilot while testing your code, added it to my answer anyway.

Comment: no, maybe that was my problem, i had a duplicate somehow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this point in your loop:

```
case 'a': 
printf("Enter a node: ");
fscanf(stdin,"%d", &x);
```

You have to add the `Add`-function:

```
Add(&head, x);
```

This can't be inside the loop, remove it:

```
struct node *head = NULL;
```

You also have a two errors in `ZeroList`. You never free the first element, and you free NULL at the end of the list. You might try this instead:

```
void ZeroList(struct node** headRef){
    struct node* current = *headRef;
    while (current != NULL)
    {
            struct node* tmp = current;
            current = current->next;
            free(tmp);
    }
    *headRef=NULL;
}
```

This is my test-run of your program:

```
a(add){x}
d(del)
l(ength)
p(rint)
z(ero)
e(xit)a
Enter a node: 1
a
Enter a node: 2
a
Enter a node: 3
p
printListprinting 3
printing 2
printing 1
```

Comment: I had `Add(&head, x);` before but I removed it for debugging, and forgot to put it back, however, it still doesn't hold anything in the loop

Comment: nvm still the same problem

Comment: thanks for finding the error, apparently, my initial problem was that I had `struct node * head = NULL`; inside the loop. How did yours ended up with this output with it inside the loop? [edit: never mind I saw your other comment]

Comment: I removed the line before I ran your program.